# Youtube Video with Bootstrap Modal issue

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, youtube, modal-dialog

I am having a small problem with my youtube video not playing and just showing black screen, I think there is some minor issue but I can't really find it.

Also here is the live demo url of the page

http://chet.world/new-design/

```
 <section class="video section text-left  position-relative" id="f">
       <div class="vid-img section-img wow fadeInRight position-absolute">
         <div class="Video-content">
             <img src="assets/images/Video-back.png" alt="">

             <a class="mfp-iframe video-play-btn video-play-cus" data-toggle="modal" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nj3CaqBT7lY" data-target="#myModal"><img src="assets/images/play.png" alt=""></a>
         </div>
       </div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row align-items-center">
                <div class="col-lg-5 section-content wow fadeInLeft">
                   <div class="video-text">
                       <h1>The professional <br> development <br/> social network for <br/> 2019</h1>

            <a class="mfp-iframe video-play-btn" data-toggle="modal" data-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/nj3CaqBT7lY" data-target="#myModal">See what we’re building</a>
                   </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
    </section>
    <!--video-->




      <!-- Video Popup-->
   <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content"> 
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">Close Video <img src="assets/images/close-btn.svg" alt=""></button>                
              <div class="modal-body">
                <!-- 16:9 aspect ratio -->
                    <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9">
                      <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="" id="video"  allowscriptaccess="always">></iframe>
                    </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

and here is the javascript / jquery source code. I think this is it but still it shows black screen.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('.video-play-btn').click(function()
{
$videoSrc = $(".video-play-btn").data( "src" );
});

</script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    // when the modal is opened autoplay it  
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function (e)
    {
        // set the video src to autoplay and not to show related video. 
        console.log($("#video").attr('src',$videoSrc));

        //$("#video").attr('src',$videoSrc + "?rel=0&amp;showinfo=0&amp;modestbranding=1&amp;autoplay=1&amp;controls=0&amp'enablejsapi=1" ); 
    });//#myModal show

    // stop playing the youtube video when I close the modal
    $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function (e)
    {
        // a poor man's stop video
        $("#video").attr('src',$videoSrc); 
        //remove modal from DOM
        //$("#myModal").detach();
    });//#myModal close

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your source is undefined on the live version. You didn't add the source for your YouTube video to your iframe.

It shows there is an iframe error on the live version src:

```
src="undefined?rel=0&amp;amp;showinfo=0&amp;amp;modestbranding=1&amp;amp;autoplay=0"
```

Should be something like this example:

```
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/tgbNymZ7vqY"></iframe>
```

Check your iframe code:

```
<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="" id="video"  allowscriptaccess="always">></iframe>
```